Automatic updates are not happening when running Chrome with Selenium
When running Chrome with Selenium, automatic updates are happening, but folders and files are not being created automatically.
It works fine on the laptop, but it doesn't work on the desktop PC.
I have no idea what the problem could be. Please help.
Just to let you know, I’m aware of webdriver_manager, but please solve it using only Selenium.

Desktop
- window 10
- python 3.12.5
- vscode studio

Laptop
- window 11
- python 3.12.5
- vscode studieo
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    print(driver)
    url = "https://www.google.co.kr/"
    driver.get(url)



When you execute it this way
Folders and files should be automatically created in the path C:\Users\cjh15\.cache\selenium.
However, on the desktop, no files are being created, and the following error occurs:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:2548/devtools/browser/02debcfe-1be1-4977-9ae1-255e14abd23e
...
...
...
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116
Current browser version is 127.0.6533.100 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:

I have no idea why this is happening
It works fine on my laptop and on a friend's computer.
I tried reinstalling Python.
I tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code.

Your error message contains the following information:
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 116
Please check the version of chrome browser you are using on your PC and laptop. Selenium uses chromedriver to distinguish between different versions.
Try replacing the chrome version or downloading a driver that matches your chrome version.

I’ve checked all updates.

The point is not to check for updates, but to ensure that Chrome browser and Chrome Driver are the same version.
Your exception message already shows that the chromedriver you are currently using is for chrome 116 version, you should download chrome 127 version, if the version is too new and there is no corresponding chromedriver, then you should reduce your chrome version

Starting from Selenium version 4 and above, the Chrome driver is automatically downloaded. It gets downloaded to the path mentioned in the text. It seems you didn't understand the essence of my question. On the laptop, it automatically downloads and matches the version correctly. However, on the desktop, it is not downloading automatically.

So, is it possible that the 116 version of chromedriver already exists on the desktop and the automatic download is not taking place? Can we try to clean up the old environment first?

Since I deleted the chromedriver folder in the .cache folder, there is nothing there now.
